# Wordpress: How to add_filter to a special div of the_content

Tags: php, wordpress, html, preg-replace

I'm trying to add a filter to only a special div of my wordpress content

sure my plugin code now will effect to all the post content, but what i need is to apply it only for a special **div class="game_req"** not the other divs ex. the **div class="how_to_play"**

my post structure:

```
<div>
    ..........
    <div class="game_req"> <!-- i need to apply filter to only this div -->
         - ball : is a round ..........
         - key : is what we need to ..........
         - caw : is an animal ..........
    </div>
    <div class="how_to_play">
         1- use the key to open .......
         2- use ball to ........
         3- use caw to .........
    </div>
    <div class="sss">
         .... key .......
         .... ball to ........
         .... caw .........
    </div>
    ..........
</div>
```

my plugin filter:

```
function myReplace_function($content){

$patterns = array(
    '/\bball\b/',
    '/\bkey\b/',
    '/\bcaw\b/'
);

$replacements = array(
    'ball ( <img src="smallImgs/ball.png" alt="ball"/> )',
    'key ( <img src="smallImgs/key.png" alt="key"/> )',
    'caw ( <img src="smallImgs/caw.png" alt="caw"/> )'
);

return preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$content);

}
add_filter('the_content','myReplace_function');
```

Comment: I found **body_class** filter but i don't know does it related to add special effect to a special div for ex. **<div class="game_req">**

Comment: I wonder, is it really hard question so no one can know the answer or give me a hint

Comment: @Tim that's all, I was thinking that you will fix my problem :D, but does [solved] or solved.. is against site rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because no one answered my question, so I decided to try many ways to fix my problem on my own

finally the solution is:

I shouldn't use a add_filter , instead I have to use add_shortcode
the changes only is replace

```
 function myReplace_function($content){
```

with

```
 function myReplace_function($attrs,$content=none){
```

also adding any specific code to be as shortcode ex. `my_shortcode`  instead of `the_content`

so my function should looks like this

```
function myReplace_function($attrs,$content=none){

$patterns = array(
    '/\bball\b/',
    '/\bkey\b/',
    '/\bcaw\b/'
);

$replacements = array(
    'ball ( <img src="smallImgs/ball.png" alt="ball"/> )',
    'key ( <img src="smallImgs/key.png" alt="key"/> )',
    'caw ( <img src="smallImgs/caw.png" alt="caw"/> )'
);

return preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$content);

}
add_shortcode('my_shortcode','myReplace_function');
```

finally I can use it by wrapping any part of my post content `[my_shortcode]...[/my_shortcode]`

so if I apply that to my question example it will be like below:

```
[my_shortcode]<div class="game_req"> <!-- i need to apply filter to only this div -->
         - ball : is a round ..........
         - key : is what we need to ..........
         - caw : is an animal ..........
</div>[/my_shortcode]
```

That's all.